# Jmeter property get/put issue

Tags: jmeter

I have the following flow,

`Thread Group 1
    -JSR223 Sampler - props.put("x",10);
 Thread Group 2
    Number of threads(users) = ${__P("x")}`

I am setting a property value which is not defined in any property file as 10. I am trying to use that value in the next thread group. But instead of ten threads, I get only 1 thread to start.

Documentation says ${__P()} would give 1 if the property is undefined. How can I set the THread Group 2's thread count to x value?

Answer (score 1):

Setting property should be

```
props.put("x","10");
```

i.e. it wants value in `String` format, and function should be `put`, not `set`.

Comment: As I said you also need to change `10` to `"10"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that value from command line, when you run the test appended by -Jx.

So when you run your test, Pass value of X from command line

```
-JPropertyName=ProperyValue
```

This will pick up value as 10.

Comment: I do not want to pass it through cmd line or property file. This is a property that I am setting from one thread group so that it can be shared by the next thread group.

Comment: In this case why don't you use JMeter variable instead of property?

Comment: Because Jmeter variable cannot be passed between thread groups!

Answer (score 0):

Thread Groups are being initialised during JMeter startup so you won't be able to set the number of threads in the Thread Group this way. You have 2 options:

1. Set the property value in *user.properties* file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) like

   ```
   x=10
   ```
2. Pass the property value `-J` or `-D` command-line arguments like

   ```
   jmeter -Jx=10 -n -t .... 

   jmeter -Dx=10 -n -t ...
   ```

The default value returned by the __P() function will **never** be 1 due to a bug in JMeter (you can report it via [JMeter Issue Tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) if you want), its default value will be an empty string. If you want the [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to return 1 as default value you should be using it like `${__P(x,1)}`

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) guide for more information on working with JMeter Properties, ways of setting and overriding them, etc.

---

Although you cannot change the number of threads on the fly, you can control how often the samplers are executed via [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer). This way you can use __P() function to set the desired throughput rate (in requests per minute) and you can change the associated property value on the fly even outside of the JMeter script.

Comment: Actually, it works. I was under the same impression as you, but I tried it and it did work (Jmeter 3). Go figure!