# JMeter in distributed mode does not creates folder based on Groovy script saved in User Defined variables

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I want to create a folder name for my results, based on a current date. I have created a variable with this value:

```
 ${__groovy(new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'))}
```

in User defined variables at the test plan level.

It works perfectly if I run the test locally - the file folder is created (e.g. 2018-01-11). 
But as soon as run the test in distributed mode, folder is created but with the name
`${__groovy(new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'))}`.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

"I would suggest running your JMeter test **on master** node (which will be collecting results from all the slaves). If you want to create a folder basing on current date you can use your operating system shell methods in order to make this folder like:

- On Windows:

  ```
  jmeter -r -n -t test.jmx -l %date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%\result.jtl
  ```
- On Linux/Unix/MacOSX

  ```
   ./jmeter -r -n -t test.jmx -l `date +%Y-%m-%d`/result.jtl
  ```

You [should not be using any Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) as they don't add any value but create unnecessary overhead which may ruin your test.

More information:

- [How to Use the Date Command in Linux](https://linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/use-the-date-command-in-linux/)
- [Windows: date command reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732776(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_examples")

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been to save the value into a property and not into a variable, specifically I saved the

```
props.put("current_date_property", new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

into a JSR223 PostProcessor at the TestPlan level.

I still do not know why it does not work for variables. But it solves my problem.

Comment: one disadvantage of this approach is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227821/jmeter-property-get-put-issue?rq=1